# Build Polygons from Polylines

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, polygon-creation, geometry-conversion

I have to build the polygons from some polylines it is an area like a main land(with some boundaries) and some islands around it,islands are building polygons and main land is missing,when i have tried to build the polygons in FME.I have snapped all the lines first and used the transformers like reader-linejoiner-polygonbuilder-writer,I am also using ArcGIS Desktop, MapInfo and QGIS.

Comment: if you use qgis: try vector-> geometry tools >lines to polygons or the plugin polygonizer

Answer (score 4):

If you have a polyline feature class and needs to convert it to polygons, use the ESRI [Feature to polygon tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003n000000). Note however, this requires an ArcInfo/Advanced ArcMap license.

Comment: If you don't have an ArcInfo license then download and install this excellent third party tool - [Tools for Graphics and Shapes](http://www.jennessent.com/arcgis/shapes_graphics.htm) - and use the Convert Polylines to Polygons tool.

Comment: I know this post is a bit old but my work recently changed its license level from advanced to the basic version and I need to convert some lines to polygons. Also my boss does not want me to download any 3rd party software on our work computers. Is there another way to work around this without the advanced license or use of 3rd party software?


Sorry if this is not the appropriate place to ask but I figured it would be better than opening a new post and repeating a topic.

Comment: @Rob, you are right. It's not the appropriate place to ask. I think it's an excellent new question, and you should really post it. Even if this is basically the same question, you have different software available (be sure to list all you have: arcgis, fme, qgis, grass...), therefore making it unique (at least from this one). However, I suspect it might be hard with a basic licence and no 3rd party software. But let the community share its combined knowledge!